# How to show warnings, errors, functions, variables in VSCode with JavaScript/Nodejs

Tags: vscode-extensions, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to show warnings (not used variables / typo), errors and an overview about my created variables and functions in an open file?

I have installed the newest Visual Studio Code IDE but if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and then <kbd>!</kbd>, my VSCode says there are no results. It doesn't know `!-command` and other commands I found in the internet.

What extension/addon do I have to install to see this? It would be great if I could see this in a separate window without using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and if the IDE would mark positions with warnings/errors in my open code as Eclipse-IDE can do.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript

Comment: I don't want to press Debug every time and set stop/breaking points. Eclipse can show me everything in real time in one separate window and mark code positions with type or not used variables etc - without testing my application. Did I overlook something in the link you posted?

Comment: The main difference here is the word `IDE`...Eclipse is an IDE, but Visual Studio Code is not an IDE, but, a code editor

Comment: If you want and IDE try https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/

Comment: Thank you. I will try it. You can write it as an answer and I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: Thanks @Meteor Newbie....done!

Comment: Do you just want a linter, like ESLint?  There is such a vscode extension, it'll show warnings and errors for many things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference here is the word `IDE`...`Eclipse` is an `IDE` and is the most widely used `Java IDE`, but, `Visual Studio Code` is not an `IDE`, but, a `code editor`.

If you want to try a `Microsoft IDE`, you can download 
`Visual Studio Community`, a fully-featured, extensible, free IDE for creating modern applications for Android, iOS, Windows, as well as web applications and cloud services https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/

Answer (score 9):

Use [Eslint](http://eslint.org/). Install it globally using the following command
`npm install -g eslint`

It will show all possible warnings based on the rule sets given, while you are coding. Moreover **VSCode** is **not an IDE** it's just Code Editor like Sublime.

As of august 2023, you can then install the Microsoft official ESLint VSCode extension and you will be able to see errors in your code :
[image]

Comment: Eslint to help you when you're using vscode. but if you want to code like you code in IDE like android studio, you can use Visual Studio Community it;s can help you.

Answer (score 5):

> Is it possible to show warnings (not used variables / typo), errors [...] in an open file?

The VS Code extension for [quick-lint-js](https://quick-lint-js.com/) can show you syntax errors and misspelled variable names. It requires no configuration. (ESLint requires per-project configuration.)

At this moment, quick-lint-js doesn't tell you about unused variables.